# STM32F103RB BxCAN Communication

Tags: stm32, can-bus, nucleo

I'm working on STM32F103RB Nucleo Board. I want to know how CAN messages are segregated in FIFO upon reception of data?. And what happens after FIFO is full(more than 3 messages)?.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: How exactly is the question unclear? Seems perfectly clear to me and two people were able to answer it. I'll vote to re-open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure a filter bank, you also specify the receive mailbox (you have 2 of them). Messages which are accepted by one filter bank goes into the associated mailbox.

FIFO (mailbox) overrun can trigger an interrupt if enabled. The behavior of the FIFO and the fate of the incoming messages are determined by the `RFLM` bit of the `CAN->MCR` register.

1. `RFLM` = 0 -> The last (3rd) message is overwritten (destroyed) by the new arriving messages. The first (oldest) 2 messages are preserved until you read them.
2. `RFLM` = 1 -> FIFO is locked. New arriving messages are discarded. The oldest 3 messages are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

> And what happens after FIFO is full(more than 3 messages)?

Then you are basically done for - you'll lose data upon Rx FIFO overflow, which is often unacceptable in CAN real-time systems. So in case your MCU is too busy to always meet the 3 message deadline, you would have to implement some ugly system with interrupts + ring buffers.

This is one reason why CAN controllers from somewhere around the late 90s/early 2000s started to use some 5 to 8 message rx buffers. BxCAN is apparently ancient, since it is worse than those 20+ years old controllers.

Hopefully you can DMA the messages, which is much prettier than the mentioned interrupt/ring buffer complexity. If that's not an option, then you should perhaps go for a modern CAN controller instead. Bascially any other CAN controller on the market has a larger rx FIFO than this one.

Comment: This CAN controller is embedded (internal) in various STM32 models. Unfortunately it doesn't have DMA support.

Comment: @Tagli Yes I know it is embedded. So if CAN is important to you, then you should probably pick another MCU. SPC5 for example, if you like ST.